# How to PasteSpecial and Use Destination Styles with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to copy a table from Excel to Word with VBA but can't figure out how to choose the necessary paste special option.

If I just use

```
Dim wApp As Word.Application
Dim wDoc As Word.Document
Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wApp.Visible = True
Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Add(Template:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Location").Cells(28, 7).Value, NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Quote Generation").Range("A1:H10").Copy
wDoc.Bookmarks("parts_table").Select
wApp.Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile
```

to paste at the bookmark, it only paste the first couple of columns regardless of what is visible. By trying it manually, Paste Special -> Use Destination Styles (S) pastes everything, but I cannot figure out how to code that.

Comment: Record a macro ;)

Comment: Start by adding `Option Explicit`. If `wdPasteEnhancedMetafile` isn't available, it will report that.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible methods. The first, which is likely to be the best option, you would have found simply by recording a macro, the second is the actual method for using destination styles.

In the examples below I have also improved your code as there is very rarely a need to select anything when working in VBA.

```
wDoc.Bookmarks("parts_table").Range.PasteExcelTable LinkedToExcel:=False, WordFormatting:=True, RTF:=False

wDoc.Bookmarks("parts_table").Range.PasteAndFormat wdUseDestinationStylesRecovery
```

Comment: That did keep the destination style which is great, but it didn't keep the columns that didn't originally fit.

Comment: @Charles - which didn't?

Comment: Sorry, neither one.

Comment: @Charles - All of the columns will have been kept, it's just that the range you have copied is evidently a lot wider than your Word document. As a result the table extends beyond the margins and either column widths will need to be adjusted to make it fit, or the page layout changed to landscape. `PasteExcelTable` will usually give the best results.